# view mysql database in windows store app

Tags: c#, mysql, database, windows-store-apps

Im developing windows store app(not a metro app) and I want to show the mysql database data on it ,I have tried many methods but all of them faild, how can i get mysql data into windows store app, please tell me about any possible way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use COnnector/Net:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming.html

Specifics on using it from a store app are here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-rt.html

Comment: how can i use MySqlConnection.GetSchema

Comment: Documentation is pretty good on that site.  Here is the docs for GetSchema:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-getschema.html